# How do I test an application in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, testing, virtual-machine

I created an application using `py2app` and have completed it. Running it on my machine has no problem, but I am concerned it might have problems such as `missing module` or other errors when run on someone else's with no programs installed. Is there a way to test this?

(sorry, I'm sure this is on the Internet but I'm not sure how to search for it)

Answer (score 0):

you really can address your concern of `module not found` and ... on your current system by testing the app in an isolated virtual environment.

you can create a virtual environment, install the necessary package in it and see if it works
to do so:

I think the fastest easiest and most comfortable way is to use `miniconda`
to create a backup of the current ( or a fresh working virtual environment) and re-create one on another (or same) machine.

`miniconda` is an environment managing tool, a super lightweight version of conda (only ~60MB)

Just install miniconda from the instructions [here](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

Then create a new environment as below:

```
conda create --name newtestevironemnet python=3.9
```

So, the command will create an environment with only python. and then you can test your app see what no module error you will get and install packages.

whenever you reach a point where everything  is working you can export necessary packages by :

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

you can also create a requirement.txt file and tell the user to do `pip install -r requirements.txt` before running the app by:

```
conda list -e > requirements.txt
```